# Пробелы в качестве разделителей тысяч php

Tags: php

Нашел только как использовать стандартные разделители, но заменить запятые на пробелы так и не получилось.
Вот пример кода.

```
<?php
$a = 999;
$b = 10999*$a;
echo number_format($b);
?>
```

https://eval.in/611658

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так:

```
<?php
$a = 999;
$b = 10999*$a;
echo number_format($b, 2, ',', ' ');
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php доки

Comment: странно это все))) это же читал это же писал, но он почему то вообще округлял, что меня в ступор и привело)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов второй параметер это сколько цифр после запятой он не округляет а обрезает т.е. сейчас получиться из числа 1000,2323 1 000,23 если надо больше ставьте второй параметр больше.